# How Do I Log Conversation Data into Local Storage in MS Bot Framework v4 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am working with Microsoft bot development framework, using its v4 node.js sdk and testing it in emulator. I have been looking for a way to save all the messages of a conversation in the local machine/storage itself. I set `persistConversationData` to true. I am completely new to Bot framework, please help me with the code part for storing the conversationData

Comment: Which SDK are you using in this, v3 or v4? Also are you looking to record production logs or just a conversation log for the emulator itself?

Comment: I am using SDK v4 and testing my codes in emulator so i need to record the conversation logs to my local disk in json/txt files.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts here depending on if you meant strictly testing-only or if you want to log during regular use.

**If you use the v4 emulator** you will see a "[save transcript as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#save-and-load-conversations-with-bot-transcripts)" button that will allow you to save a copy of the current conversation for later use and replaying within the emulator.

**If you would like to create your own logging middleware** there is a built in class called `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`

In order to set it up you can do the following (using the built-in, finished subclass called `ConsoleTranscriptLogger` in this case, but you can implement the built-in interface `TranscriptLogger` to create a custom version to save copies if desired)

Import the middleware classes in your require statement via the following:

```
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, MemoryStorage, ConversationState, TranscriptLoggerMiddleware, ConsoleTranscriptLogger } = require('botbuilder');
```

Then initialize an instance of that logger class:

```
const logger = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new ConsoleTranscriptLogger());
```

Finally include that middleware on your overall middleware stack:

```
// Create conversation state with in-memory storage provider.
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);

// Create the main dialog.
const myBot = new MyBot(conversationState);

adapter.use(logger); // initialize middleware after your usual setup steps
```

In this case, after these steps are done `ConsoleTranscriptLogger` will print out the data received to your console. A full implementation of custom logging with saving is much more involved but can be done by creating a class that implements [`TranscriptLogger`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/db9c461e1d1c1099adb16a0ff46f7e5bf478b01a/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/transcriptLogger.ts#L143) and simply saves the state instead of outputting to console as seen in [`ConsoleTranscriptLogger`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/db9c461e1d1c1099adb16a0ff46f7e5bf478b01a/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/transcriptLogger.ts#L127)

**Custom Logging**
Within [this repo](https://github.com/nyxsys/loggerbot) I've set up custom logging as well. This requires adding two files.
In this case

[`CustomLogger.d.ts`](https://github.com/nyxsys/loggerbot/blob/master/CustomLogger.d.ts) contains the import and setup for implementing the `TranscriptLogger` interface

[`CustomLogger.js`](https://github.com/nyxsys/loggerbot/blob/master/CustomLogger.js) contains the logic for processing incoming activities